# How long a script has been running?

Tags: php

How can I check how long my `exec()` script has been running for? The output would be something like this:

`1 Day(s) 2 hours 23 minutes 12 seconds`

I don't want it to output more then 60 seconds like this

`1 Day(s) 2 hours 23 minutes 118 seconds`

My code:

```
$start = time();
$s = time() - $start;
$m = floor($s / 60);
$h = floor($m / 60);
$msg = "script running for approx: Seconds - $s | Minutes - $m | Hours - $h";
echo $msg;
```

Comment: You never call `exec()` in your script.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the seconds part on 60 with `/` you will get the exact mins add the to your mins and then divide the seconds part with `%` you will get the remaining second, which are less than 60.

**Edit**

Even you might have problem with your mins as well. change that too

```
$start = time();
$s = time() - $start;
$m = floor($s / 60);
$h = floor($m / 60);

$mins = ($m %  60);
$seconds =  ($s % 60);

$msg = "script running for approx: Seconds - $seconds  | Minutes - $mins | Hours - $h";
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 2):

If using PHP 5.4, this is gives the exact amount of time spent in PHP

```
$runtime = round(microtime(TRUE) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'], 6);
echo "Script running for $runtime seconds";
```